# Wordpress /users/me endpoint request forbidden

Tags: rest, wordpress

Using Wordpress's plugin **WP REST API** version 1, there is an endpoint called `/users/me` which response with data for the currently logged-in user. When I requested `/users/me` I got `403 Request Forbidden` error. But If I requested `/users/1` (where 1 is the user ID) then everything works. So why am I getting 403 error for `/users/me` endpoints? I'm using Postman to send my request:

THIS WORKS (userID 1 is the currently logged-in user):

```
http://example.com/wp-json/users/1?access_token={myAccessToken}
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/users/me?access_token={myAccessToken}
```

However, when using **WP REST API** version 2, `/users/me` works but it only returns a subset of what version 1 would have returned. The data is incomplete by comparison (i.e. email, first name, last name ...etc)

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?access_token={myAccessToken}

{
    "avatar_urls": {
        "24": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/29b3ef85f13fedb43f84e6cb4a634e73?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
        "48": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/29b3ef85f13fedb43f84e6cb4a634e73?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
        "96": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/29b3ef85f13fedb43f84e6cb4a634e73?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
    },
    "description": "",
    "id": 1,
    "link": "http://example.com/author/admin/",
    "name": "admin",
    "url": "",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it tagged [ios] and [afnetworking-2]? The question has nothing to do with these.

Comment: I originally suspected AFNetworking for iOS was mucking around with the request endpoints, hence and AFNetworking tag. Anyhow, I removed the those tags.